# Spotify Android SDK - Cant import player library

Tags: android, android-studio, spotify

I am trying to integrate spotify with my android application. I am using their Android SDK with Android Studio. I followed the [tutorial](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/tutorial/) on their official developer guide. I can import and use the authentication api (import com.spotify.sdk.android.authentication;) but cant import the player api (import com.spotify.sdk.android.player;)

Anybody faced this problem or any leads?

EDIT:

I added these dependencies in build.gradle file:

```
// This library handles authentication and authorization
compile 'com.spotify.sdk:spotify-auth:1.0.0-beta10@aar'
// This library handles music playback
compile 'com.spotify.sdk:spotify-player:1.0.0-beta10@aar'
```

Now I tried to try out the demo code mentioned in the link above. But I am getting error in these imports.

```
import com.spotify.sdk.android.player.Spotify;
import com.spotify.sdk.android.player.ConnectionStateCallback;
import com.spotify.sdk.android.player.Player;
import com.spotify.sdk.android.player.PlayerNotificationCallback;
import com.spotify.sdk.android.player.PlayerState;
```

However I can import the authentication related imports.

```
import com.spotify.sdk.android.authentication.*;
```

Either the player library is not getting imported properly or the import definitions have changed in 'com.spotify.sdk:spotify-player:1.0.0-beta10@aar' version, since the demo code that has been given is for 'com.spotify.sdk:spotify-player:1.0.0-beta9@aar' version.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on why you can't import it? Error messages? What did you try?

Comment: @MichaelThelin Added edits in question.

Comment: I must have made some mistake while importing libraries. Its working now. Thanks.